# Python-social-auth: do not reassociate existing users

Tags: django, python-social-auth

I'm using python-social-auth to allow users to login via SAML; everything's working correctly, except for the fact that if a logged-in user opens the SAML login page and logs in again as a different user, they'll get an association with both of the SAML users, rather than switch login.

I understand the purpose behind this (since it's what you can normally do to associate the user with different auth services) but in this case I need to enforce a single association (ie. if you're logged in with a given SAML IdP, you cannot add another association for the same user with the same provider).

Is there any python-social-auth solution for this, or should I cobble together something (for instance, preventing logged-in users from accessing the login page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no standard way to do it in `python-social-auth`, there are a few alternatives:

- Override the login page and if there's a user authenticated, then log them out first, or show an error, whatever fits your projects.
- Add a `pipeline` function and set it in the top that will act if `user` is not `None`, you can raise an error, logout the user, etc.
- Override the backend and extend the `auth_allowed` method in it return `False` if there's a valid user instance at `self.strategy.request.user`. This will halt the auth flow and `AuthForbidden` will be raised.